# Wireless interface not working

Tags: networking, wireless, ethernet

I am having trouble connecting to my Wi-Fi network. The network was working fine up until recently, but it suddenly stopped working. I have tried restarting my computer and my router, but the problem persists.

I have run the lshw -class network command and the output is as follows:

```
*-generic DISABLED

description: Wireless interface
product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
logical name: wlo1
version: ff
serial: d4:1b:81:a3:c4:85
width: 32 bits
clock: 66MHz
capabilities: bus_master vga_palette cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8821ce driverversion=6.2.0-26-generic firmware=N/A latency=255 link=no maxlatency=255 mingnt=255 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
resources: irq:151 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:84000000-8400ffff
*-network
description: Ethernet interface
physical id: 11
bus info: usb@1:1
logical name: enx160bf7e81578
serial: 16:0b:f7:e8:15:78
capabilities: ethernet physical
configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=6.2.0-26-generic duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.117.141 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair

I am not sure what else to do to troubleshoot this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided, your wifi link looks to be disabled.

Here's some basic commands to troubleshoot generic networking issues.  Each command has a man page and most are rich with option switches.  Sorry but I am hard wired to the network so the snippets display ethernet link results and not wifi.  But the process is identical.  For DHCP (no fixed IP address assigned) you need to be able to reach the wifi router, ethernet router or switch.  In your case pinging the IP address for your router likely won't work so your particular problem is very basic.

ip  [COMMAND]

frankie@ubuntu-m8h:~$ `ip link`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 70:4d:7b:2d:77:94 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1441 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 500
    link/none
```

Things to look for:  Link being UP and having a hex MAC address.  If the wireless link isn't listed at all then you probably have a hardware or possibly a driver problem.

frankie@ubuntu-m8h:~$ `ip a`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 70:4d:7b:2d:77:94 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.15/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s31f6
       valid_lft 2063sec preferred_lft 2063sec
    inet6 fe80::effd:9dde:6ef8:ad83/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1441 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 10.11.18.146/24 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7cdb:3f07:2ad0:f7c0/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Things to look for:  That an IP address is assigned to the link in question.  If not you likely have a network layer problem.

nmcli  [COMMAND] [ARGUMENTS]

frankie@ubuntu-m8h:~$ `nmcli device status`

```
DEVICE     TYPE      STATE                   CONNECTION    
enp0s31f6  ethernet  connected               Auto Ethernet 
tun0       tun       connected (externally)  tun0          
lo         loopback  unmanaged               --
```

Ping

frankie@ubuntu-m8h:~$ `ping localhost`

```
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.038 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.032 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.032 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.028 ms
^C
--- localhost ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3062ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.028/0.032/0.038/0.003 ms
```

If Ubuntu isn't detecting your Wi-Fi network at all, or if you're getting errors, then you can try installing or reinstalling the Wi-Fi drivers from the Ubuntu ISO file.  There is ample information on this forum to learn how to do that.

`lsusb` or `lspci` depending on what sort of a wifi device you have installed.

frankie@ubuntu-m8h:~$ `sudo lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Q170/Q150/B150/H170/H110/Z170/CM236 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 31)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f1)
00:1b.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #20 (rev f1)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Z170 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus (rev 31)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V (rev 31)
02:00.0 SATA controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller (rev 02)
03:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller
```

frankie@ubuntu-m8h:~$ `sudo lshw -C network`

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 31
       serial: 70:4d:7b:2d:77:94
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.15.0-82-generic duplex=full firmware=0.7-4 ip=192.168.0.15 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:126 memory:df200000-df21ffff
```

Based on the results from the lsusb or lspci commands, this will confirm (or not) that Ubuntu can see the wireless device. If so, you can assume that the firmware is working but the system has no idea how to talk to the device. This is where drivers or modules are needed.

```
sudo lsmod
```

Lists the modules that are present. To activate a module, type the following command where "modulename" is the name of your chipset.

```
sudo modprobe modulename
```

In your case the modulename would be something like RTL8821CE

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Restarts the network service.  If you removed the Network Manager or uninstalled it by accident this command will fail. If so, you have no Internet and no Network Manager.

```
sudo apt install network-manager
```

if none of the above works, you may need to edit your configuration file.

```
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

It should look something like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
 
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

Then restart the interface (using the link name for your device):

```
sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup -v wlan0
```